# Query Related to Sql

Tags: c#, sql

this query give me a error "unclosed quatation marks after string "myCOnnection " how to resolve it .

```
INSERT INTO Company_Master
(C_Name,M_Name,L_No,Tax_No,PO_No,Location,State,Country,Telephone,Fax_No,Email_Id,
Website,Currency_Name,Company_logo,APT,APF) VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + 
textBox2.Text +"','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + 
textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + 
textBox8.Text + "','" + textBox9.Text + "','" +textBox10.Text+"','"+ 
textBox11.Text+"','"+textBox12.Text+"','"+textBox13.Text+"','" + 
pictureBox1.Image+"','" + dateTimePicker1.Value+"','"+dateTimePicker2.Value+"')" 
myConnection);
```

Comment: Don't patch your query together like this. Use *Prepared Statements*

Comment: your problem is much bigger than error message about quotations marks

Answer (score 4):

you forgot to put comma after closing insert query before myConnection

Answer (score 4):

Put comma after query:

```
         string query="INSERT INTO Company_Master
         (C_Name,
          M_Name,
          L_No,
          Tax_No,
          PO_No,
          Location,
          State,
          Country,
          Telephone,
          Fax_No,
          Email_Id,
          Website,
          Currency_Name,
          Company_logo,
          APT,APF) 
  VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "',
         '" + textBox2.Text + "',
         '" + textBox3.Text + "',
         '" + textBox4.Text + "',
         '" + textBox5.Text + "',
         '" + textBox6.Text + "',
         '" + textBox7.Text + "',
         '" + textBox8.Text + "',
         '" + textBox9.Text + "',
         '" +textBox10.Text+"',
         '"+ textBox11.Text+"',
         '"+textBox12.Text+"',
         '"+textBox13.Text+"',
         '" + pictureBox1.Image+"',
         '" + dateTimePicker1.Value+"',
         '"+dateTimePicker2.Value+"')";

 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
```

and this is not a good way, always use parameterized queries.

See [Example **HERE**](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/459498/SQL-INSERT-statements-in-Csharp)

Comment: Instead of adding 'myConnection' this way, use (query, myConnection). Use the insert statement solely on its own. I've found this method to be a little more simplistic.

Comment: thanks @clerktech i forgot to set it, but now fine\

Comment: you're welcome @Ehsan Sajjad. just something I have learned to do. keeps connection and query separate which helps with debugging.

Comment: yes it helps, but much better approach is to use Stored procedures or at least parameterized quereis